# sql server 2005 - select records from tbl A contained WITHIN a text field of tbl B

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005

I'm trying to work out a SQL Select in MS SQL 2005, to do the following:

`TABLE_A` contains a list of keywords... asparagus, beetroot, beans, egg plant etc (x200).
`TABLE_B` contains a record with some long free text (approx 4000 chars)...

I know what record within `TABLE_B` I am selecting (byID).

However I need to get a shortlist of records from `TABLE_A` that are contained WITHIN the text of the record in `TABLE_B`.

I'm wondering if SQLs CONTAINS function is uselful... but maybe not.

This needs to be a super quick query.

Cheers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It will never be super quick because of the LIKE and wildcard at each end. You can not index it and there are no whizzy tricks. However, because you have already filtered TableB then it should be acceptable. If you had a million rows in tableB, you could go for coffee while it ran

```
SELECT
    A.KeyWordColumn
FROM
    TableA A
    JOIN
    TableB B ON B.BigTextColumn LIKE '%' + A.KeyWordColumn+ '%'
WHERE
    B.ByID = @ID --or constant etc
```

CONTAINS can be used if you have full text indexing: but not for a normal SQL query

Comment: Thank you both!!!

Hoping that CONTAINS may speed things up a bit... i'll give it a try.

Comment: Any suggestions how I might use CONTAINS to speed things up in this context... code gratefully received! :)

Comment: Sorry, I've never used FTS. Try this though: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=full-text-search+CONTAINS to get other questions related to FTS

Answer (score 0):

I would try this

select keyword from table_a, table_b
where table_b.text like '%' + keyword + '%'
and table_b.Id = '111'

Comment: where's the relation ship between a and b?

Comment: the only relationship is that given by the like!